# Can I use Azure Mobile (Zumo) authentication with SPA apps on a mobile device?

Tags: authentication, mobile, cordova, single-page-application, azure-mobile-services

I'm interested in using Azure Mobile services with SPA applications... perhaps with PhoneGap and or Kendo.UI as well.

I would like to add authentication to my app, and am looking at Azure Mobile Services.  What isn't clear to me is if I can use Zumo (mobile services) to authenticate my app?

Example

1. User downloads app from store (or uses HTML5 caching to store the app)
2. The SPA app connects to Azure Mobile to get the OAUTH credentials
3. The Credentials secure my REST calls to the database (as secured by Azure Mobile)

Can anyone clarify if this architecture is possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can definitely do this.  If you go into the quickstart page after creating a new Mobile Service, you'll see one of the supported platforms is HTML/JS.  You can download that quickstart application to run a local website that will connect to your Mobile Service and can set up authentication using this flow (http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/mobile/tutorials/get-started-with-users-html/).  Dropping this into a PhoneGap application is very simple and just requires downloading the jQuery and Mobile Service javascript files locally (phonegap can't reference remote JS files).  The bulk of the HTML can be the exact same.  You'll just need to take the JS from the HTML/JS quickstart and drop it into the onReady method (I believe that's what PhoneGap calls once the device is ready for you to use).  Hope that helps.